# delphi 2010 datasnap return treeview from server

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, datasnap

is it possible in Delphi Datasnap 2010 to transfer treeview from Datasnap 2010 server to DataSnap Client?

thanks

Comment: Please explain "transfer treeview".

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to kludge something together that creates and populates a VCL control on the server and serialize the control to the client, but it seems ugly.

I would have it return the data that represents a tree and use that to populate a treeview on the client side, instead.

```
NodeId  NodeName  ParentId
0       Root      -1
1       Node1     0
2       Node2     0
3       Node3     0
4       Node1.1   1
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of transferring GUI elements from servers to clients, it is a common practice to transfer the data only (for example as 'data transfer objects', DTO) which can easily be (de-)serialized using open source libraries like [OmniXML](http://www.omnixml.com/), [NativeXML](http://www.simdesign.nl/xml.html) or [SuperObject](http://www.progdigy.com/?page_id=6).

The presentation layer can change easily (think of HTML or mobile clients) this way.

The definition for DTO can be found on [Martin Fowler's](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataTransferObject.html) site.

Answer (score 0):

DataSnap can serialize objects using JSON. I recommend you create a tree structure in which you would store the nodes and then populate your treeview accordingly.

And no, you cannot serialize a VCL TTreeView.